# Removing these trailing characters from text in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with text in Python and trying to remove trailing characters. I am aware of the `rstrip` function but it unfortunately does not get rid of the trailing characters due (I think) to the nature of the trailing characters. Below is a minimally reproducible example I would appreciate your help with.

```
x="test string\\r\\n\\"
x.rstrip()
```

What I need to get as a result is "text string" but I am getting `test string\\r\\n\\` in other words nothing gets removed.

Please advise. Thank you in advance.

Comment: the `\\r` and `\\n` re considered as a string not the special carecter that's why you can't user the `rstrip` you can use `split` the get the wanted string

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
# Note this is an ordereddict (default in Py3.8+)
mapping = {
  r'\\r': '\r',
  r'\\n': '\n',
  r'\\':  '\\' # keep this line last
}

def unescape(escaped_string):
    t = escaped_string
    for s, r in mapping.items():
        if s in t:
            t = t.replace(s, mapping[s])
    return t.strip()
```

Example use

```
x = r"test string\\r\\n\\"
y = unescape(x)
print("Str with escaped chars")
print(f"       in: '{x}'")
print(f" repr(in): {repr(x)}")
print("\nStr with unescaped chars")
print(f"      out: '{y}'")
print(f"repr(out): {repr(y)}")
print("\nStripped and unescaped")
fin = y.replace('\\','').strip()
print(f" stripped: {repr(fin)}")
```

Result

```markdown
Str with escaped chars
       in: 'test string\\r\\n\\'
 repr(in): 'test string\\\\r\\\\n\\\\'

Str with unescaped chars
      out: 'test string
\'
repr(out): 'test string\r\n\\'

Stripped and unescaped
 stripped: 'test string'
```